# How to login google account when use google driver API in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I have followed the instructions in google doc and am able to login and use Driver Api on my debug but when I run on release and on playStore the login fails and cannot use Driver service Api.

My code Login:

```
  GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA),new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                .build();
        GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
        startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), RQ_CODE_LOGIN);
```

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == RQ_CODE_LOGIN) {
                handleSingInData(data);
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            MyApplication.trackingEvent("login_false");
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_login_false), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

build gradle:

```
//gg drive api
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
```

OAuth consent screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I2Au.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3DWg.png)

I've tried everything I can find but I don't know what the error is